# How to read variable-length strings with h5py

Tags: hdf5, h5py

I'm trying to use h5py to read an array of variable length strings from an HDF5 file created in C. For a simple example, I used the variable length string array example from the HDF5 group, h5ex_t_vlstringatt.c at https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/examples/api-c.html. I compile with h5pcc  and the example program runs fine (it reads in the file it writes and prints out the contents).

However, I just get an empty object in python; with a simple example program

```
import h5py                                                                      
fnam = 'h5ex_t_vlstringatt.h5'                                                   
data = h5py.File(fnam, 'r')                                                      
print data['DS1']
```

I get

```
<HDF5 dataset "DS1": shape None, type "<i4">
```

Also, I'm using an anaconda distribution of python that I just updated, so h5py is version ~2.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downloading the file from the link:

```
2148:~/mypy$ h5dump h5ex_t_vlstringatt.h5 
HDF5 "h5ex_t_vlstringatt.h5" {
GROUP "/" {
   DATASET "DS1" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_STD_I32LE
      DATASPACE  NULL
      DATA {
      }
      ATTRIBUTE "A1" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
            STRSIZE H5T_VARIABLE;
            STRPAD H5T_STR_SPACEPAD;
            CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
            CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
         }
         DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 4 ) / ( 4 ) }
         DATA {
         (0): "Parting", "is such", "sweet", "sorrow."
         }
      }
   }
}
}
```

In a Ipython session

```
In [167]: f = h5py.File('h5ex_t_vlstringatt.h5', 'r')
In [168]: list(f.keys())
Out[168]: ['DS1']
In [169]: f['DS1']
Out[169]: <HDF5 dataset "DS1": shape (), type "<i4">
In [170]: f['DS1'].attrs
Out[170]: <Attributes of HDF5 object at 2826604252>
In [171]: list(f['DS1'].attrs.keys())
Out[171]: ['A1']
In [172]: f['DS1'].attrs['A1']
Out[172]: array([b'Parting', b'is such', b'sweet', b'sorrow.'], dtype=object)
```

The strings are stored in an attribute of the dataset, not as the value of the set.

Comment: Ah, exactly so. Everything works great now. I still don't know how to write a dataset of variable-length strings, but at least in my application it makes more sense to write them as an attribute anyway.

Comment: Have tried http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/special.html#variable-length-strings?  I've responded to a few SO questions about this.

Comment: I did see this tutorial, but I'm interested in writing variable length strings from C rather than from python. I should have followed h5ex_t_vlstring.c from https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/examples/api-c.html, but writing the string array as an attribute turned out to make sense for me.